# Подключение к веб-сервису через SOAP с сертификатом

Tags: php, запрос, soap, веб-служба

Пытаюсь подключиться к веб-сервису через SOAP. В наличии сертификат p12 для подключения. Поизучал этот вопрос и пришел к следующему: сертификат нужно преобразовать в .pem для использованием с soap client. Преобразовал (использовал openssl-функцию - `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts`).

Процесс подключения:

```
$wsdl           = 'https://domain.com:8077/iicwebservice.asmx?wsdl';
$certificate    = __DIR__ . '/certKeys/my.cert.pem';
$password       = '111111';

$options = array(
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'exception'     => true,
    'local_cert'    => $certificate,
    'passphrase'    => $password,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

В итоге в ответ получаю:

> Couldn't load from 'https://domain.com:8077/iicwebservice.asmx?wsdl' :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "https://domain.com:8077/iicwebservice.asmx?wsdl"

Путь к сертификату проверен, он в порядке.

Попробовал подключиться через SoapUI, подключение прошло с первого раза. Правда сертификат положил в ориигнальном виде (.p12).

Подскажите решение.